Convert Vec<T> to Vec<U> where T and U are of different size without memory leak
I have the following struct:
#[repr(C)]
pub struct BinaryCandle {
    pub open: f64,
    pub high: f64,
    pub low: f64,
    pub close: f64,
    pub volume: f64,
    pub time: i64,
}

and the following function to convert a Vec<u8> to a Vec<BinaryCandle>:
pub fn owned_vec_from(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Vec<BinaryCandle>, BinaryError> {
    // Do not deallocate buffer for the original Vec as it has the
    // same memory space as the returned Vec.
    let mut bytes = core::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(bytes);

    // Ensure capacity equals length.
    // If not, we could leak memory, or have extra allocated memory
    // that is not a proper multiple of BinaryCandle.
    bytes.shrink_to_fit();

    let ptr = bytes.as_ptr().cast::<BinaryCandle>();

    Self::check_alignment(ptr)?;
    Self::check_length(&bytes)?;

    // Unchecked division is safe as size is non-zero.
    let len = bytes.len() / Self::size();

    // SAFETY: Pointer is guaranteed to be non-null, and properly aligned.
    // We have asserted the memory range is a valid length/multiple for BinaryCandle.
    // BinaryCandle does not implement Drop, so we do not risk a double free.
    // Original Vec will not be deallocated.
    // By calling shrink_to_fit first, we ensure we are not leaking any memory,
    // as the capacity will equal the length once that function is called.
    unsafe { Ok(Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr.cast_mut(), len, len)) }
}

I've made the assumption that shrink_to_fit() will always deallocate all extra capacity, but that does not seem to be the case based on the docs, The docs for shrink_to_fit() say the resulting Vec may still have excess capacity.
I've thought about using into_boxed_slice() which mentions Before doing the conversion, this method discards excess capacity like shrink_to_fit.. However, into_boxed_slice() just internally calls shrink_to_fit() so I don't think I can be sure it doesn't leak memory either.
Any ideas on how to ensure the shrunk Vec will always be the exact length?

Are you sure you need that? According to the documentation, this depends on the implementation of Allocator, so you don't have any control over this. If the allocator decides it's best not to shrink entirely (for reasons like memory granularity or performance), then you should accept that. For example, if an allocator only ever allocates buffers sized a multiple of 512, you can tell it to give you 510, it will still give you 512. The proper way would be to accept that and handle it in your code properly.

I'd love to show you how that would look, but sadly your example is not a [MRE]. So I cannot compile your code without making wild assumptions.

@Finomnis I think you're right about the allocation. In my head I didn't want a scenario where the returned Vec was pushed to without a proper multiple of extra allocated bytes (if there were extra bytes). However, because I am manually setting capacity equal to length, any pushes will reallocate, and the old allocation will be freed entirely (extra bytes included) as the pointer originally given by the allocator never changes. Just overthinking this I guess.

I don't think you're overthinking it that much. size_of::<BinaryCandle>() * len has to equal bytes.capacity() exactly, or you'll invoke UB.

This is not sufficient even ignoring your sizing quandary. The minimum alignment of types must be the same. It doesn't matter that the allocation is currently aligned to BinaryCandle, when deallocated it must have the same layout as it was originally allocated with. See GlobalAlloc::dealloc. So unless you handle destruction of Vec<BinaryCandle> specifically or use #[repr(packed)] to match u8 alignment, this isn't allowed. This is one of the safety requirements of from_raw_parts that you missed.

Instead of checking everything yourself (and getting it wrong, probably) just use bytemuck.

@kmdreko is ‘#[repr(C)]’ and my alignment check not enough? The alignment check ensures the pointer evenly divides into the alignment of my struct.

@MarkLisoway You misunderstood what I said, what alignment the pointer happens to have is not relevant. You would need BinaryCandle to have the same alignment as u8.

Let me offer you a higher level take: If what you are trying to implement is serialization/deserialization of data, I recommend using some serde compatible data format instead. If size is very important to you, you could even consider protobuf. You can of course simply cast raw bytes, but as you see in this discussion, there are a lot of pitfalls, and some more that weren't even mentioned here yet, like endianess.

@Finomnis I was moreso just trying to learn for a for-fun project. I think I've got it correct now using #[repr(C, packed)] so that u8, and BinaryCandle alignemnt are the same (that was the invariant I was missing). As well as an extra check to make sure Vec<u8> buffer pointer is on an 8 byte boundary for CPU reads, while still using addr_of! to read the fields as they are packed.
